# How to add condition via views_query_alter() to filter a multi-value select field that does not contain a value?

Tags: views

I have _views_query_alter() hook that I need to filter out nodes whose multi-value select does **not** contain a value ("National"). The code below works to show the nodes that **do** contain "National" but I need to do the opposite and cannot get it to work due the field being a multi-value field.

```
function HOOK_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {

  if ($view->id() == 'state_landing_page') {
    $field = 'field_resource_location_type';
    $value = 'National';
    $operator = '=';
    $query->addWhere('conditions', $field, $value, $operator);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out nodes that do not contain the value "National" in a multi-value select field, you can use the following code instead

```
function HOOK_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
      if ($view->id() == 'state_landing_page') {
        foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
          foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
             if ($condition['field'] == 'node.field_resource_location_type') {
              $condition = [
                'field' => 'node.field_resource_location_type',
                'value' => 'National',
                'operator' => '<>',
              ];
            }
          }  
        }
      }
    }
```

The operator **<>** or **!=** is used to exclude nodes that contain the value "National" in the field. This should work for multi-value fields as well. The **<>** operator and **!=** operator are equivalent in MySQL, so either one will work in this case.

Comment: Thank you but I had tried this and is does not work as expected. If a node's Location Type field has "National" plus another value (Virtual, for example), then it still shows in the results. I can't get to work via the Views UI using filters either as their is no operator for the multi-value list for "Does not include"

Comment: You can try my code updated code. That's worked for me. I tried this base on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/10

Comment: Thank you, your code works. The issue ended up being with the View being a Search API index that needed to be rebuilt for some reason and was causing it to not query properly.